# Having to import PySpark classes/methods in very piecemeal fashion

Tags: pyspark, python-import

I am spinning up on Python and PySpark, installed using Anaconda on
Windows 10.  For now, I'm working through `sparkbyexamples.com` pages,
e.g., [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark-tutorial),
[here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/different-ways-to-create-dataframe-in-pyspark),
[here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-rename-dataframe-column).

I'm surprised by how many classes and methods need to be imported in a
piecemeal fashion, e.g., SparkSession, StructType,StructField,
StringType, IntegerType, Row, col, Column, etc.  Not all the imports
are specified in the tutorial material, so one has to recursively
search the `*.py` files in the `%SPARK_HOME%` subtree to find them,
e.g., using `find`, `sed`, and/or `vimgrep`.   This is not efficient.

I would expected that for efficient analytics, many classes and
methods that are used in a particular application domain would be
accessible in a single import, or a few imports.  How do Python users
avoid the need to go hunting for the right classes/methods and
importing them in a piecemeal fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid importing multiple symbols you can directly import a module/namespace and then use that namespace to access the required symbols. This will make your imports cleaner and more concise.

```
from pyspark.sql import types as T, functions as F

schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('firstname', T.StringType(), True),
    T.StructField('middlename', T.StringType(), True),
    T.StructField('lastname', T.StringType(), True)
])
```

Comment: Thanks, I've marked the answer as correct because it sounds sensible, and in fact, I was wondering why the tutorial does otherwise.  I thought that there must be a reason why they don't do as you suggest.  The fact that they don't, together with the fact that they sometimes neglect to mention that an import is needed, sends the newbie reader on a wild goose chase to locate the invoked class or method.

Comment: I agree...sometimes tutorials can be confusing. That's why we have Stackoverflow :-) Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe they want avoid prefixes like `T` and `F` to improve readability for the newbie.  But that's just kicking the pain down the road, and not even far down the road, when the cited classes/methods don't work and one has to find the module source code files.